# ImageView is zooming in on table row deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios7.1

When I delete a row from my table view, the image I have in the cell will come to the front of the screen and zoom all the way back to the end of the cell when the cell slides left to delete. I can provide a gif of this if necessary, but I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically keep the imageView in each cell from responding to the deletion animation at all.

Comment: http://gfycat.com/FeistyIckyAsiaticgreaterfreshwaterclam

Comment: weird, are you using a `UITableViewCell` or you're using a subclass?

Comment: I'm using UITableViewCell when I create each cell

Comment: Please post related code